# How is the Council Medal of Honor Medal bonus applied?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

The "Council Medal of Honor" medal has the following listed as one of the choices:

"+1 Aim and +1 Will for each mission without any soldier deaths (to a maximum of +10 each)."

Does anyone know if the bonus is either:

- Retroactive *(since the beginning of the game)*
- Only starts counting once the medal is given
- Only applied to missions that specific solider (with the medal) is on?

Comment: i've been wondering about this too.

Comment: Guys, *"retrospective"* means thinking back on something that happened.  The word you want is *"retroactive."*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The medal's bonuses are not retroactive and only start once the medal is awarded. The two bonuses are:

- **+1 Aim and Will for each mission completed with no soldier deaths, up to a maximum of +10**.
  Bonus is dependent upon when soldier is awarded and each mission
  awarded soldier participates in. If awarded soldier only participates
  in two missions out of X missions, the soldier will only receive +1
  Aim & Will on the second mission. *The awarded soldier must
  participate in eleven missions without any soldier deaths to receive
  maximum benefit* (+10 Aim & Will).
- **Provides 10 Aim and Critical Chance if not within 7 tiles of an
  allied unit.**
  Bonus offers instant utilization without much drawback or relying on soldier mission attendance. Best awarded to MEC Troopers, Shotgun Assaults or Squad Sight Snipers as these soldiers tend to be apart from other soldiers.

[Source](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Medals_%28EU2012%29)

Comment: Does it reset if a soldier dies while the awarded soldier is on the mission?

Answer (score 4):

I've only awarded that medal relatively recently, but

- Not retroactive (starts once the medal is given)
- Only counts missions your awarded soldier is on.